# vue.js proper way to determine empty object

Tags: vue.js

Classic scenario: I want to display a list, but when it's empty I want to display "No data".

The fact that it is somewhat complicated to do something I would expect to be simple makes me think I'm probably doing it wrong.

Here is my current solution.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="element">
  <div v-if="empty">No item in inventory</div>
  <div v-for="(index, item) in inventory">
    {{item.key}}<button onclick="remove('{{index}}')">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";
var vm;
$(function() {
    vm = new Vue({
        el: '#element',
        data: {
            inventory: {"id1" : {"key" : "val1"}, "id2" : {"key" : "val2"}},
            empty: false
        },
        watch: {
            inventory: function() {
                vm.empty = $.isEmptyObject(vm.inventory);
            }
        }
    });
});

function remove(key) {
  Vue.delete(vm.inventory, key);
}
</script>
```

Is there a better solution than this?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can just use length of `inventory` in `v-if`, like following:

```
<div id="element">
  <div v-if="!inventory.length">No item in inventory</div>
  <div v-for="(index, item) in inventory">
      {{item.key}}
      <button v-on:click="remove(index)">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Given that `inventory` variable is a hash and not an array, you can use any of the following to find it is empty and use that in `v-if`:

[ECMA 5+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility):

```
Object.keys(inventory).length === 0
```

Pre-ECMA 5:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }

    return JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify({});
}
```

As you are already using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/), you can also do:

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject({}); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="element">

  <div v-if="isEmpty">No item in inventory</div>
  <div v-for="(index, item) in inventory">
      {{item.key}}<button @click="remove(index)">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";
var vm;
$(function() {
    vm = new Vue({
        el: '#element',
        data: {
            inventory: {"id1" : {"key" : "val1"}, "id2" : {"key" : "val2"}},
            empty: false
        },
        methods: {
            remove: function(index) {
                Vue.delete(this.inventory, index);
                
            }
        },
        computed: {
           isEmpty: function () {
              return jQuery.isEmptyObject(this.inventory)
           }
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. inventory is not an array, it's an object, and objects don't have ".length" property.

Comment: @Finch_Powers I had missed that, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried <div v-if="Object.keys(inventory).length === 0">No item in inventory</div> as well as jQuery.isEmptyObject(inventory); and it doesn't work. I have a warning that states that vue cannot evaluate the expression.

Comment: @Finch_Powers Updated the answer, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7r4sp0kk/) as well.

Comment: Ok cool! But it's still much more complicated than calling ".length" on a list. So you think there is no "as easy" solution when data is an object?

Comment: Object.keys(yourObject).length === 0 this really works!

Comment: In your first example, that should be `v-if="!inventory.length"` (if not has any length)

Answer (score 19):

After searching for a few minutes, I come up with a better solution to check whether the **object** is empty or not.

```
Object.keys( YOUR_OBJECT ).length == 0 // Check if it's empty.
```

It will return **0** if it's empty. If you want to check whether the **array** is empty or not you can definitely go for this solution below,

```
YOUR_ARRAY.length == 0  // Check if it's empty.
```

In my case it's an **object**, not **array**. So, it may also help. Happy coding :)

Comment: For me `Object.keys(YOUR_OBJECT).length` waas enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If it's an array, you can use

```
v-if="!array.length"
```

Answer (score 3):

Worked Great for me...

```
v-if="array.length == 0"
```

Comment: This gives a warning `Comparison array.length == 0 may cause unexpected type coercion`. While `v-if="!array.length"` doesn't. That's because of the double equal instead of the triple.

Comment: Seconded what @ILovePHP mentioned above. The best practice in JavaScript is to use `===` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div v-if="Object.length > 0 ">
  //Write your logic here
</div>
<div v-else>
 No Records found
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is an object, you can check the length of the array of its keys. Otherwise, if it is an array, you can directly check its length.

For Objects:

```
<div v-if="Object.keys(yourObj).length">
  // display your object here
</div>
<div v-else>
 No Records found
</div>
```

For Arrays:

```
<div v-if="yourArray.length">
  // display your array here
</div>
<div v-else>
 No Records found
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use this
v-if="(YOUR_OBJECT).total == 0"